# Get result of a sign in with redirect method in vuex + Firebase application

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, vuex

I'm using Firebase for authentication in my Vuex application. 
As per the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#getredirectresult) I can call

```js
authentication.signInWithRedirect(provider);
authentication.getRedirectResult().then(userCredentials => {
// work with my user credentials here...
});
```

This, however, does not seem to work for me.
What ends up happening is that the `getRedirectResutl()` method gets called just before the redirect to the Google authentication page, and when I come back from that page nothing happens.

How can I obtain redirect results?

`onAuthStateChanged` method seems to work but I'd like to work with `UserCredentials`.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I have to call `getRedirectResult` inside the component to which Google redirects me after the sign in is complete.

So, the correct usage is to call `getRedirectResult` in the `mounted` method of the component that is responsible for the page to which the user is redirected.